# UITableView with custom control, change value of UILabel when particular button pressed on cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

All

It might possible the same question asked many times in different manner. But my condition is somewhat different.

I have table where I have around 10 cell, now each cell have different custom controls(i.e. UILabel, UIButton) etc.

Now I want when I click button on cell 0 it change label(custom UILabel and not cell label) value on the same cell, without reload whole table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes is your custom cell class you assign the property to UiButton like this

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnAdd;
```

and next thing in this method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you write like this code

```
 cell.btnAdd.tag=indexPath.row;
 [cell.btnAdd addTarget:self action:@selector(AddMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and in this class write this code

```
   -(void)AddMethod:(UIButton *)btnAdd
  {
  NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btnAdd.tag inSection:0]; // if section is 0
            customcell *cell = (customcell*)[maintableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.yourlabelname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[yourlabelname.text intValue] + 1];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update perticular cell of UITableview just you have store indexPath of that row and use following methods to update it .

```
[self.myTablviewname beginUpdates];

[self.myTablviewname reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:button.indexPath]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.myTablviewname endUpdates];
```

Also you can give animation to row as per your convenience.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have this option where whole row updated with animation, but I don't want that. I just need to change particular label value, like we done with simple view label and button.

Comment: Yes you can do like that just set UITableViewRowAnimationNone.

Comment: That's fine but my UILabel value is not coming from array through which I bind that UITableView, so without that how can I change value of any particular label in that cell.

Comment: You can set tag to each label as per row in which it is and then you can access it depending upon tag. Can you just add screenshot of your tableView then it clear the idea.